# TRANSACTION statement in POSTGRESQL for creating table

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, etl

I have to create a table through ETL in redshift. First, I am loading the data in a temporary table and then transacting it to the main table. The approach below is good when I want to update a data for a particular period. If I have just created the main_table and it doesn't have any data then how do the TRANSACTION and DELETE statements work for initial upload of data in main_table. I am new to ETL process.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

DELETE FROM main_table 
USING  temporary_table
WHERE main_table.id  = temporary_table.id
AND main_table.time_stamp = temporary_table.time_stamp

INSERT INTO main_table 
SELECT * FROM temporary_table ;

END TRANSACTION;
```

Comment: If main table is empty there won't be any rows deleted in the first command, and in the second all rows from temp table will be inserted. Was your concern that you get an exception for the table being empty?

Comment: yes, I had that concern. So,  I could use the same command lines for initial upload in the table? if nothing is being deleted then, IS WHERE clause playing any role here?

Comment: If main table is empty, the where clause will just transfer an empty set to the deletion task. That's a normal operation. After that, execution will carry on with the insert statement.